# Fluent NHibernate question

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Let's say you have two tables, "Users" and "UserRoles".  Here's how the two tables are structured (table - columns):

Users - UserID (int)

UserRoles - UserID (int), Role (string)

What I want is for my "User" class in my domain to have an IList of roles.  How do I construct my Fluent NHibernate mapping to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is a of a set of elements, which in standard hbm mapping is:

```
<set name="Roles" table="UserRoles">
  <key column="UserID" />
  <element column="Role" />
</set>
```

For Fluent NHibernate you can map this like so:

```
HasMany<string>(x => x.Roles)
  .AsElement("Role");
```

You may need to also specify the key name using `WithKeyColumn(string)`.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW this has change minorly of present day. The current mapping is

```
HasMany<string>(x => x.Roles)
  .Element("Role");
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive it would be

```
public User()
  {
    Id(x => x.UserID);
    HasMany<UserRoles>(x => x.UserRoles).AsBag();
  }
```

You'll also have to make sure you map your UserRoles class as well

Comment: The thing is UserRoles isn't a class.  It's just a list of strings.  The datatable isn't linking two foreign keys, just one foreign key (UserID) and a role name (string).

Answer (score 0):

This also worked:

```
HasMany<Role>(u => u.Roles)
                .WithTableName("UserRoles")
                .Component(role => role.Map(r => r.Name))
                .AsList();
```

You don't need to map Role or UserRoles.

Make sure Role implements `IEquatable < Role > ;.`