# Mapping a list of Enums

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, enums, string, mapping

I have a table called UserPermissions with a FK to the users table by userId and then a string column for the string value of an enum.

The error I am seeing is NHibernate.MappingException: An association from the table UserPermissions refers to an unmapped class: GotRoleplay.Core.Domain.Model.Permission

My Permission Enum:

```
    public enum Permission
{
    [StringValue("Add User")]
    AddUser,

    [StringValue("Edit User")]
    EditUser,

    [StringValue("Delete User")]
    DeleteUser,

    [StringValue("Add Content")]
    AddContent,

    [StringValue("Edit Content")]
    EditContent,

    [StringValue("Delete Content")]
    DeleteContent,
}
```

The property in my User class:

```
public virtual IList<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
```

My database table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserPermissions
(
UserPermissionId            int                 IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
UserId                      int                 NOT NULL,
PermissionName              varchar (50)        NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT PK_UserPermissions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (UserPermissionId),
CONSTRAINT FK_UserPermissions_Users FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Users(UserId),
CONSTRAINT U_User_Permission UNIQUE(UserId, PermissionName)
)
```

My attempt at mapping the permissions property of my user object:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions)
             .WithParentKeyColumn("UserId")
             .WithChildKeyColumn("PermissionName")
             .WithTableName("UserPermissions")
             .LazyLoad();
```

What am I doing wrong that it can't map the permission to a list of enum values?

Comment: So after a lot of tinkering, I ended up having to create a new object called UserPermission and map it to the UserPermissions table with a Permission property using my enum as the datatype.  This works fine, but permissions can be attached to roles and users, meaning my select query to get EVERY permission assigned to a user (including all their roles) requires a complicated set of linq statements. I'd rather not do that.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would post the code that I chose for my solution.  It's only a workaround.  I wish Fluent would support Enum lists, but until it does, here's a possible solution:

The Enum - This is my enum, your standard enum.

```
public enum PermissionCode
{
    //site permissions 1-99
    ViewUser = 1,

    AddUser = 2,

    EditUser = 3,

    DeleteUser = 4
}
```

Next, I have my Permission class.

```
public class Permission
{
    public virtual int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual string PermissionName { get; set; }

    public virtual PermissionCode PermissionCode 
    {
        get
        {
            return (PermissionCode)PermissionId;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have an ID and a name, and then a property that converts the Id into my PermissionCode enum.

The mapping looks like this:

```
public class PermissionMap : ClassMap<Permission>
{
    public PermissionMap() 
    {
        WithTable("Permissions");

        Id(x => x.PermissionId).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.PermissionName);
    }
}
```

Since the PermissionCode property is derived, we don't do anything in the mapping.

My Table structure behind the mapping looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Permissions
(
    PermissionId                    int                 NOT NULL,
    PermissionName                  varchar (50)        NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Permissions PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PermissionId)
)
```

If you wanted to use the name instead of the integer value, with some slight modifications you can.  It depends on your personal preferences.

Answer (score 3):

here is the way which worked for me

```
HasMany(x => x.Licences)
                .WithTableName("DriverLicence")
                .AsElement("Level").AsBag();
```

look here for more information [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432809/fluent-nhibernate-question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type so that NHibernate can convert the value in the table to a member of the Permission enum.

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Permissions)
         .WithParentKeyColumn("UserId")
         .WithChildKeyColumn("PermissionName")
         .WithTableName("UserPermissions")
         .LazyLoad()
         .CustomTypeIs(typeof(Permission));
```

Edited to add:
I'm sorry, I should have noticed that you had this as ManyToMany. That's not possible: You can't have a Users collection (other side of m:m) hanging off an enum. You need to define this as 1:m or create a Permission table and class and map that as m:m.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion and CustomTypeIs does not exist as a valid option. I tried instead using .CollectionType(typeof(Permission)) but I still see the same error: An association from the table UserPermissions refers to an unmapped class: GotRoleplay.Core.Domain.Model.Permission