# FluentNHibernate: How to handle one-to-many values when the many is a simple enum

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

It seems like the following scenario shouldn't be uncommon, but I can't figure out how to handle it in FluenNHibernate:

```
public class Product: BaseEntity
{
    public Product()
    {
        Categories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    ...
}

public enum Categories
{
    Classic = 1,
    Modern = 2,
    Trendy = 3,
    ...
}
```

So, I need a ProductCategories table that allows me to map one product to many categories, but I don't think NHibernate will handle this unless I have an actual Categories class and a Categories table with a many-to-many relationship specified.  There are a number of reasons this is not desirable, not the least of which is that it's overkill.

I'm using AutoMapper - any way I can override to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried the concatenated string in another instance like this, but I really wanted something that didn't need to be transformed every time.  As it turns out, I found a very similar question here:  [Map to a list of Enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423927/map-to-a-list-of-enums).  As described there, this override works:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Product> mapping)
{
     mapping.HasMany(x => x.Categories).KeyColumn("ProductFk").Table("CategoriesProductsMap").Element("Category").AsBag();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614050/fluentnhibernate-how-to-handle-one-to-many-values-when-the-many-is-a-simple-enum/3622023#3622023) worked for me, however the enum was mapped as in int.

To get it to map as a string (my preference) I adapted the mapping as follows:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Account> mapping)
{
    mapping
        .HasMany(x => x.Categories)
        .Table("CategoriesProductsMap")
        .Element("Category", e => e.Type<NHibernate.Type.EnumStringType<Category>>())
        .AsSet();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, none of them as straightforward as you might expect. While NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate do quite well with a single `enum`, a collection is significantly more troublesom.

Here are a couple of approaches:

1. Persist the collection to a single `nvarchar(?)` column by concatenating the members.
2. Mark the `enum` with the `Flags` attribute and collapse the list as a bitmask (this will require just one integer column)

In either case, you can have NHibernate access a field that contains the "collapsed" values; the getters of the public properties will transform the collapsed values to collections. The getter of the collapsed value will transform the collection into a single string (1) or integer (2).

You'd have to map `Product` explicitly:

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(Reveal.Member<Product>("_categories"))
            .Access.Field();
    }
}
```

So although `Product` exposes an `IList<Category>`, NHibernate will only get and set the value of the `_categories` field;

Answer (score 0):

At work, while it did not concern a collection of enum value, we created a custom type (by implementing `IUserType` to store a `IDictionary<CultureInfo, string>`.

We converted the dictionary into a xml document (XDocument) and we stored the data in an Xml column in Sql Server, although any string column could store the value.

You can see [this site](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx) for information about implementing `IUserType`.